# AngularJS performance in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, dom, bindonce

I am building an application with AngularJS, and I am facing problems with the firefox. I think it's because I use multiple ng-repeat inside others ng-repeat, I have already tried almost all what I found in stackoverflow and forums.

I have a big table with multiple loops, this is what the table looks like :

```
<table class="booking-table table table-condensed mergeCells"
    id="booking-table" ng-if="bookingSelected.accounts.length != 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" class="transparent separator"></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #000 !important;">OPPORTUNITY
                DEFINITION</th>
            <td class="separator"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">REGION</th>
            <th>COUNTRY</th>
            <th>MARKETS</th>
            <th>SERVICE</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>CUSTOMER</th>
            <th>BDO Ref</th>
            <th style="width: 100px !important;">Probability %</th>
            <th style="width: 110px !important;">Booking Revenue</th>
            <th class="gray" style="width: 10px !important;">Nb</th>
            <th class="gray" style="width: 221px !important;">Name</th>
            <th class="separator"></th>
            <th class="transparent po-info left"
                style="text-align: center;">PO Number</th>
            <th class="transparent po-info left"
                style="width: 80px !important; text-align: center;"
                colspan="2">PO Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody bindonce
        ng-repeat="account in bookingSelected.accounts track by account.id">
        <!-- Booking line -->
        <tr class="gray">
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="10" class="separator"><span
                class="remove-opp button-hover" ng-if="isNotReadOnlyAdmin()"
                ng-click="addOpportunity(account)"><i
                    class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</span><span
                class="remove-opp button-hover readOnlyButtons"
                ng-if="isReadOnlyAdmin()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add</span> <span class="remove-opp button-hover"
                ng-if="account.id == null && currentUser.isAdministrator"
                ng-click="removeAccount(account)"><i
                    class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove Account</span></td>
            <td colspan="2">BOOKING GOALS</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="separator"></td>
            <td class="po-info"></td>
            <td class="transparent right po-info input number" colspan="2">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }"
                ng-model="account.bookingGoals" class="input-number"
                ng-change="totalAccountOpportunity(account)"></input> <span
                class="suffix">€</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gray">
            <td colspan="2" class="transparent text-red">REMAINING
                BOOKING GOALS proba weight</td>
            <td class="po-info"></td>
            <td class="transparent right po-info input"
                ng-class="{'text-red' : account.remaining > 0, 'text-green' : account.remaining <= 0}"
                colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ account.remaining | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Account -->
        <tr class="orange" bindonce
            ng-repeat-start="opportunity in account.opportunities track by opportunity.id">
            <td class="remove-opp" ng-if="showRemoveButton(opportunity)"
                ng-click="removeOpportunity(account, opportunity)">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </center>
            </td>
            <td class="center input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                ng-if="showRemoveButton(opportunity)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="REGION"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" type="text" ng-model="account.title"></td>
            <td class="center input" colspan="2"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                ng-if="!showRemoveButton(opportunity)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="REGION"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" type="text" ng-model="account.title"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="COUNTRY" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.country"
                ng-options="country as country.libelle for country in countries track by country.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="MARKET" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.market"
                ng-options="market as market.libelle for market in markets track by market.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="SERVICE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.service"
                ng-options="service as service.libelle for service in services track by service.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="TYPE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.type"
                ng-options="type as type.libelle for type in types track by type.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="CUSTOMER" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.client"
                ng-options="customer as customer.raisonSociale for customer in customers track by customer.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">{{
                opportunity.bdoNumber }}</td>
            <td class="right input"
                ng-class="{'green' : opportunity.probability.value >= 90, 'orange' : opportunity.probability.value == 60, 'red' : opportunity.probability.value == 30, 'gray' : opportunity.probability.value < 30}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="Probability %" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.probability"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunity(account, opportunity)"
                ng-options="probability as probability.libelle for probability in probabilities track by probability.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="right input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <div ng-if="showPoAmmount(opportunity)">
                    <span> {{ opportunity.poAmmount | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                style="width: 30px;"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="Nb" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.nb"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                style="width: 300px !important;"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="OPPORTUNITY DEFINITION" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opportunity.definition"></td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="center po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                ng-model="opportunity.revenue" uib-popover="REVENUE"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" class="input-number"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunity(account, opportunity)">
            </td>
            <td class="right po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <div ng-if="showPoAmmount(opportunity)">
                    <span> {{ opportunity.poAmmount | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="remove-opp" title="Add opportunity"
                ng-if="isNotReadOnly()"
                ng-click="addOpportunityChildren(opportunity)">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </center>
            </td>
            <td class="remove-opp readOnlyButtons"
                title="Add opportunity (disabled)" ng-if="isReadOnly()">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Opportunities -->
        <tr bindonce
            ng-repeat="opp in opportunity.opportunities track by opp.id"
            ng-class="{'active' : opp == activeOpp}">
            <td class="center input rowSpan" colspan="2"
                test="{{ account.title }}" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">
                {{ account.title }}</td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                ng-model="opp.country" uib-popover="COUNTRY"
                popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-options="country as country.libelle for country in countries track by country.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="MARKET" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opp.market"
                ng-options="market as market.libelle for market in markets track by market.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="SERVICE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opp.service"
                ng-options="service as service.libelle for service in services track by service.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="TYPE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opp.type"
                ng-options="type as type.libelle for type in types track by type.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="CUSTOMER" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opp.client"
                ng-options="customer as customer.raisonSociale for customer in customers track by customer.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" style="padding-left: 5px !important;"
                ng-class="{'redB' : opp.bdoNumber == null || opp.bdoNumber == ''}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">{{ opp.bdoNumber }}</td>
            <td class="right input"
                ng-class="{'green' : opp.probability.value >= 90, 'orange' : opp.probability.value == 60, 'red' : opp.probability.value == 30, 'gray' : opp.probability.value < 30}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><select
                uib-popover="Probability %" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="opp.probability"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunityChild(opp, account)"
                ng-options="probability as probability.libelle for probability in probabilities track by probability.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="right input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ opp.poAmmount | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 30px;" class="input"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="Nb" popover-trigger="'focus'" uib-popover="Nb"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" ng-model="opp.nb"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }"
                uib-popover="OPPORTUNITY DEFINITION" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                type="text" ng-model="opp.definition"></td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="center po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                ng-model="opp.po" uib-popover="PO Number"
                popover-trigger="'focus'">
            </td>
            <td class="right po-info input number"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="PO Amount"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" ng-model="opp.poAmmount"
                class="input-number"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunityChild(opp, account)"></input>
                <span class="suffix">€</span></td>
            <td ng-if="isNotReadOnly()"><i
                class="fa fa-chevron-up remove-opp" title="Move up"
                ng-click="opportunityToUp(opportunity, opp)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-chevron-down remove-opp" title="Move down"
                ng-click="opportunityToDown(opportunity, opp)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-times remove-opp" title="Remove opportunity"
                ng-if="showRemoveButton(opp)"
                ng-click="removeOpportunityChildren(opportunity, opp, account)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-clone remove-opp"
                title="Duplicate opportunity"
                ng-click="duplicateOpportunityChildren(opportunity, opp)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-eye remove-opp" title="Show history"
                ng-click="showHistory(account, opportunity, opp)"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#opportunityHistory"></i></td>
            <td ng-if="isReadOnly()" class="readOnlyButtons"><i
                class="fa fa-chevron-up remove-opp" title="Move up (disabled)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down remove-opp"
                title="Move down (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-times remove-opp"
                title="Remove opportunity (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-clone remove-opp"
                title="Duplicate opportunity (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-eye remove-opp" title="Show history (disabled)"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Total -->
        <tr class="total" ng-if="$last">
            <td colspan="10" class="separator"></td>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL {{ account.title }}</td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="center" colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ opportunity.total }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="($index + 1) < bookingSelected.accounts.length"
            ng-repeat-end>
            <td colspan="16"
                style="height: 10px !important; border: none !important; background: #fff !important;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr class="separator"></tr>
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="12">TOTAL SUM</td>
        <td class="separator"></td>
        <td class="total-sum"></td>
        <td class="center total-sum" colspan="2">
            <div>
                <span> {{ totalBooking | number }} € </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using now the **bindonce** module.

In Google Chrome I have no problems with the performance, it's only in Mozilla firefox (I tried multiple version of this browser, all have the same issue).

Bellow is a snapshot of the firefox performance tool :

[image]

**UPDATED**

```
<table class="booking-table table table-condensed mergeCells"
    id="booking-table" ng-if="::bookingSelected.accounts.length">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" class="transparent separator"></th>
            <th colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid #000 !important;">OPPORTUNITY
                DEFINITION</th>
            <td class="separator"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">REGION</th>
            <th>COUNTRY</th>
            <th>MARKETS</th>
            <th>SERVICE</th>
            <th>TYPE</th>
            <th>CUSTOMER</th>
            <th>BDO Ref</th>
            <th style="width: 100px !important;">Probability %</th>
            <th style="width: 110px !important;">Booking Revenue</th>
            <th class="gray" style="width: 10px !important;">Nb</th>
            <th class="gray" style="width: 221px !important;">Name</th>
            <th class="separator"></th>
            <th class="transparent po-info left"
                style="text-align: center;">PO Number</th>
            <th class="transparent po-info left"
                style="width: 80px !important; text-align: center;"
                colspan="2">PO Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody bindonce
        ng-repeat="account in bookingSelected.accounts track by $index">
        <!-- Booking line -->
        <tr class="gray">
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="10" class="separator"><span
                class="remove-opp button-hover" ng-if="isNotReadOnlyAdmin()"
                ng-click="addOpportunity(account)"><i
                    class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</span><span
                class="remove-opp button-hover readOnlyButtons"
                ng-if="isReadOnlyAdmin()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add</span> <span class="remove-opp button-hover"
                ng-if="account.id == null && currentUser.isAdministrator"
                ng-click="removeAccount(account)"><i
                    class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove Account</span></td>
            <td colspan="2">BOOKING GOALS</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="separator"></td>
            <td class="po-info"></td>
            <td class="transparent right po-info input number" colspan="2">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }"
                ng-model="::account.bookingGoals" class="input-number"
                ng-change="::totalAccountOpportunity(account)"></input> <span
                class="suffix">€</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gray">
            <td colspan="2" class="transparent text-red">REMAINING
                BOOKING GOALS proba weight</td>
            <td class="po-info"></td>
            <td class="transparent right po-info input"
                ng-class="{'text-red' : account.remaining > 0, 'text-green' : account.remaining <= 0}"
                colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ ::(account.remaining | number) }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Account -->
        <tr class="orange" bindonce
            ng-repeat-start="opportunity in account.opportunities track by $index">
            <td class="remove-opp" ng-if="::showRemoveButton(opportunity)"
                ng-click="removeOpportunity(account, opportunity)">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </center>
            </td>
            <td class="center input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                ng-if="::showRemoveButton(opportunity)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="REGION"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" type="text"
                ng-model="::account.title"></td>
            <td class="center input" colspan="2"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                ng-if="::(!showRemoveButton(opportunity))"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="REGION"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" type="text"
                ng-model="::account.title"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="COUNTRY" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.country"
                ng-options="country as country.libelle for country in countries track by country.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="MARKET" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.market"
                ng-options="market as market.libelle for market in markets track by market.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="SERVICE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.service"
                ng-options="service as service.libelle for service in services track by service.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="TYPE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.type"
                ng-options="type as type.libelle for type in types track by type.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="CUSTOMER" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.client"
                ng-options="customer as customer.raisonSociale for customer in customers track by customer.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">{{
                ::opportunity.bdoNumber }}</td>
            <td class="right input"
                ng-class="{'green' : opportunity.probability.value >= 90, 'orange' : opportunity.probability.value == 60, 'red' : opportunity.probability.value == 30, 'gray' : opportunity.probability.value < 30}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="Probability %" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.probability"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunity(account, opportunity)"
                ng-options="probability as probability.libelle for probability in probabilities track by probability.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="right input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <div ng-if="::showPoAmmount(opportunity)">
                    <span> {{ ::(opportunity.poAmmount | number) }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                style="width: 30px;"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="Nb" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.nb"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"
                style="width: 300px !important;"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="OPPORTUNITY DEFINITION" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opportunity.definition"></td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="center po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                ng-model="::opportunity.revenue" uib-popover="REVENUE"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" class="input-number"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunity(account, opportunity)">
            </td>
            <td class="right po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)">
                <div ng-if="::showPoAmmount(opportunity)">
                    <span> {{ opportunity.poAmmount | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="remove-opp" title="Add opportunity"
                ng-if="::isNotReadOnly()"
                ng-click="addOpportunityChildren(opportunity)">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </center>
            </td>
            <td class="remove-opp readOnlyButtons"
                title="Add opportunity (disabled)" ng-if="::isReadOnly()">
                <center>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Opportunities -->
        <tr bindonce
            ng-repeat="opp in opportunity.opportunities track by $index"
            ng-class="{'active' : opp == activeOpp}">
            <td class="center input" colspan="2"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">{{ ::account.title }}</td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                ng-model="::opp.country" uib-popover="COUNTRY"
                popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-options="country as country.libelle for country in countries track by country.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="MARKET" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opp.market"
                ng-options="market as market.libelle for market in markets track by market.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="SERVICE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opp.service"
                ng-options="service as service.libelle for service in services track by service.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="TYPE" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opp.type"
                ng-options="type as type.libelle for type in types track by type.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(null)"><select
                uib-popover="CUSTOMER" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opp.client"
                ng-options="customer as customer.raisonSociale for customer in customers track by customer.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="input" style="padding-left: 5px !important;"
                ng-class="{'redB' : opp.bdoNumber == null || opp.bdoNumber == ''}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">{{ opp.bdoNumber }}</td>
            <td class="right input"
                ng-class="{'green' : opp.probability.value >= 90, 'orange' : opp.probability.value == 60, 'red' : opp.probability.value == 30, 'gray' : opp.probability.value < 30}"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><select
                uib-popover="Probability %" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                ng-model="::opp.probability"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunityChild(opp, account)"
                ng-options="probability as probability.libelle for probability in probabilities track by probability.id">
            </select></td>
            <td class="right input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ opp.poAmmount | number }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 30px;" class="input"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                uib-popover="Nb" popover-trigger="'focus'" uib-popover="Nb"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" ng-model="::opp.nb"></td>
            <td class="input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }"
                uib-popover="OPPORTUNITY DEFINITION" popover-trigger="'focus'"
                type="text" ng-model="::opp.definition"></td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td class="center po-info input" ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)">
                <input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" type="text"
                ng-model="::opp.po" uib-popover="PO Number"
                popover-trigger="'focus'">
            </td>
            <td class="right po-info input number"
                ng-click="makeRowActive(opp)"><input
                ng-model-options="{ debounce: 600 }" uib-popover="PO Amount"
                popover-trigger="'focus'" ng-model="::opp.poAmmount"
                class="input-number"
                ng-change="updatePoAmmountOpportunityChild(opp, account)"></input>
                <span class="suffix">€</span></td>
            <td ng-if="::isNotReadOnly()"><i
                class="fa fa-chevron-up remove-opp" title="Move up"
                ng-click="opportunityToUp(opportunity, opp)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-chevron-down remove-opp" title="Move down"
                ng-click="opportunityToDown(opportunity, opp)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-times remove-opp" title="Remove opportunity"
                ng-if="::showRemoveButton(opp)"
                ng-click="removeOpportunityChildren(opportunity, opp, account)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-clone remove-opp"
                title="Duplicate opportunity"
                ng-click="duplicateOpportunityChildren(opportunity, opp)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-eye remove-opp" title="Show history"
                ng-click="showHistory(account, opportunity, opp)"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#opportunityHistory"></i></td>
            <td ng-if="::isReadOnly()" class="readOnlyButtons"><i
                class="fa fa-chevron-up remove-opp" title="Move up (disabled)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down remove-opp"
                title="Move down (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-times remove-opp"
                title="Remove opportunity (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-clone remove-opp"
                title="Duplicate opportunity (disabled)"></i> <i
                class="fa fa-eye remove-opp" title="Show history (disabled)"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Total -->
        <tr class="total" ng-if="::$last">
            <td colspan="10" class="separator"></td>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL {{ account.title }}</td>
            <td class="separator"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="center" colspan="2">
                <div>
                    <span> {{ opportunity.total }} € </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="::(($index + 1) < bookingSelected.accounts.length)"
            ng-repeat-end>
            <td colspan="16"
                style="height: 10px !important; border: none !important; background: #fff !important;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr class="separator"></tr>
    <tr class="total">
        <td colspan="12">TOTAL SUM</td>
        <td class="separator"></td>
        <td class="total-sum"></td>
        <td class="center total-sum" colspan="2">
            <div>
                <span> {{ ::(totalBooking | number) }} € </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you are using angular 1.3 and above, one-way data binding comes built in. Just use `{{::myScopeVariable}}`  - same goes for `ng-repeat`ed items. Not sure about performance on Moz, but maybe try using [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) to check what scopes are you binded to?

Comment: One-way bindings would be my recommendation as well. I've experienced similar issues when I have to build a bunch of ng-options inside of an ng-repeat and one-way bindings helped a lot.

Comment: thanks for your replies, I don't think {{ ::myVar }} will help, because all my data can be changed by the user, the user can change everything in the table (by using inputs, selects, ...) so I think {{ ::myVar }} will not be changing if somthing change in the scope, or not ?

Comment: I added an update of my table, it's faster now but still lagging in Mozilla browser, can you give it a look to see if I do well ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to use this in all app: 
{{ ::(opportunity.poAmmount | number) }}
function in ng-if and bg-class is a pure evil

ng-if="::showRemoveButton(opportunity)"

refactor ng-if="bookingSelected.accounts.length != 0" =>  ng-if="::bookingSelected.accounts.length"

but remember that bind-once inside ng-if is very fragile/ you should return undefiend from function if data do not get yet from server

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I give it a try, the view is faster now in Chrome, but I'm still having lags in Mozilla browser, any suggestion ?

Comment: too heavy snippet. for webkit it is normal, but not for gecko or momile device